# Defining a function with a function as an argument

Tags: function, functional-programming, ocaml

I am currently trying to define a function of type ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a which takes a function of type 'a -> 'a and an argument of type 'a and calls the function twice on the argument. I'm relatively new to OCaml but I do know how to define a function, but I had no luck with trial and error or Google trying to get a function to take a function as an argument and then apply that function twice.

Any tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

edit: Thanks to Jeffrey below, my problem is now solved.

## let f4 g a = g (g a );;

val f4 : ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCaml infers types, so if you use an argument as a function, it infers that it's a function. Here's an example:

```
# let f g = g 8 + g 10;;
val f : (int -> int) -> int = <fun>
# (~-);;
- : int -> int = <fun>
# f (~-);;
- : int = -18
```

To understand the example, note that `(~-)` is the ordinary integer negation operator.

**Update**: A hint for your more complicated problem. You need to *test* the value of `n`. Maybe an `if` statement would work? Second hint: if you use recursion, you don't need to use a loop. If you want to use a loop, don't use recursion. (Personally I'd suggest using recursion, it's like playing scales while learning piano.)

Comment: This is very close to what I need, but I need it to literally take 'a for everything. 

It should come out with ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a

when trying # let f4 g a = g a * g a ;;  I get
val f4 : ('a -> int) -> 'a -> int = <fun>

which is close, but not quite ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a

any suggestions?

Comment: Right, I don't want to just give you the answer! The problem with this latest attempt is that the `*` operator works only on ints. Try doing an operation that's not tied to a particular type (like, say making a list or a tuple).

Comment: # let f4 g a = g a :: g a ::[];;

val f4 : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b list = <fun>

again I'm close. How would I get everything to be 'a? (The way I've learned the language is spotty, I'm not impressed with the teaching style so my knowledge is very gappy)

Comment: Actually, never mind, I think. As long as I'm not missing anything # let f4 g a = g (g a );;
val f4 : ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a = <fun> 

appears to work?

Comment: Actually I have a twist to this. If I wanted to first take an integer n and apply the function n times (int -> ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a) how would I begin this? Any tips?

I know how to begin the declaration, I'm just not sure how to apply a function n times to something.

Comment: You want to solve recursively. For recursion, you need to know what to do when you're done (the trivial case for applying the function 0 times) and you need to know how to take the answer for a smaller problem (n - 1 times) and get the answer you want. I hope this helps. Your previous answer was 20 characters or so, and this new one will be around 60. I.e., it's not that hard.

Comment: I'm familiar with how to do this, just not sure how to implement.

let rec f5 n g a = g a, but then i'm not exactly sure how to make the recursive call with n-1. If only this were java... We've done nothing really with recursion yet in OCaml and i've never programmed functional before.

Comment: Here is what I tried, and it's closeish:

let rec f5 n g a = 
   g a;
   f5 (n-1) g a;;
val f5 : int -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'c = <fun>

Comment: I have tried this also # let rec f5 n g a = 
  g a
  while n > 0 do
   f5 (n-1)
  done ;; but this gives a syntax error and isn't correct obviously.

Comment: @BMEdwards37: Just as a suggestion, instead of asking a totally different question (about how to do recursion) in the comments, it's probably better just to ask another question. Comments are not really well-designed for that kind of thing — you can't even put linebreaks in them.